How can I change the frequency of a sine wave from a look-up table
I've set an ISR to calculate the sine value for every index of the table up to 200 (the length of the array), then the calculated value is offset by multiplying half the period register then adding another half. After that, the final value is assigned to the duty cycle register (multiplied by 2 because the period register is 15-bit and the duty cycle register is 16-bit).
How can I calculate the sine wave and change it's frequency without the "index/resolution" part? Basically, I want to get rid of that part and use the classic sinewave formula: Ampsin(wt), where w = 2pif.
Here's the code I have so far:
int sineWave[SPWM_RES]; // Sine wave lookup table
int sineWave180[SPWM_RES]; // Sine wave lookup table

volatile int sineIndex = 0; // Sine wave index
float Amp_coef = 0;

void __attribute__((__interrupt__, no_auto_psv)) _T3Interrupt(void) //This is the Timer3 interrupt function
{
    
    IFS0bits.T3IF = 0; // Clear Timer3 interrupt flag

    float sine = Amp_coef * sin(2 * M_PI * sineIndex / SPWM_RES);
    sineWave[sineIndex] = (int)((P1TPER/2) * sine + P1TPER/2);
    sineWave180[sineIndex] = (int)((P1TPER/2) * (-sine) + P1TPER/2);
    
    P1DC1 = sineWave[sineIndex] * 2; // Set duty cycle from lookup table
    P1DC2 = sineWave180[sineIndex] * 2;
    
    if(SPWM_RES == sineIndex)
    {
        sineIndex = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        ++sineIndex;
    }
    //sineIndex = (++sineIndex) % SPWM_RES; 
    
}

I want to get rid of array index part and change the frequency, but don't quite get it.

Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, it is not a forum. Also read "[ask]" and other pages of the [help] to avoid beginner's problems. Then come back and [edit] your question to clarify.

How long does your (unknown to us) MCU take to calculate the sine? Does that meet your requirements for the ISR?

Your code excerpt needs to be replaced by a [mre] that shows the issue. Why do you fill the sine wave table again and again? Commonly you do this once for the runtime.

To realize frequency changes, you can use for example something like the Bresenham algorithm. This needs some math background, which you need to research yourself.

How are the sinewave*{} arrays used? You need to find out before deciding how to change this. I don't understand this function. If it uses an array to avoid the computational cost of calculating sine each time, then it fails to do that as it calculates the sine on each call. If it uses the array for something else, then what?
